# Google Analytics : Difference in values of site metrics under Roll up properties and individual properties?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am getting difference in values of the site metrics among the roll up id and individual property id .

Answer (score 0):

Rollup means that properties is getting data from multiple sites, while individual accounts refer to single sites. This said rollup value’s should be greater than properties with individual sites. 
Hopefully this help. If that’s not the case please elaborate your question, to get better idea regarding your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick turn around but i understand completely that roll up property is integrating different properties data . I have segregated the roll up property ids data into individual property in one of my custom reports in GA . but still it does not match up with the individual property data . Please get back if you are still unable to understand the concern .

Thanks